# Django-Allauth Google OAuth get approved scopes

Tags: django, django-allauth

I have added additional Google API scopes to my Django application. I wanted to check if the user has approved the other scopes. I searched online and found references to **scopes in the extra_data**. But I couldn't find it. Appreciate any help in checking if the user has approved the extra scopes.